# how to call controller method from javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in ruby on rails, I want to call controller method from javascript with multiple parameters. I tried but didn't got output.
**_applied_candidate.html.erb**

```
<p>Next Status: <span class="fontstyle3">

          <select name="workflow_id" id="workflow_id" onchange="updateItem('workflow_id', <%= applied_candidate.id %>, <%= job.id %>)">         
            <% data.each do | d | %>                  
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <% d.next_step.split(',').each do | s | %>
                  <% data1 = CandidateWorkFlow.select(:workflow_step).where("step_id = ?",s) %>                   
                   <% data1.each do |l| %>
                      <option value=<%= s%>> <%= l.workflow_step %> </option>          
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>                   
            <% end %>
          </select>  
        </span>
        </p>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateItem(item, userID, jobID) {
    var e = document.getElementById(item);
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
    new Ajax.Request('/jobs/update_work_flow', { 
                  method: 'post',
                  parameters: { selected_id: item, u_id: userID, job_id: jobID }
                });


};</script>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :jobs do
    get :update_work_flow,  on: :collection
```

end

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
def update_work_flow
redirect_to root_path
```

end

How to check controller method called or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On routes.rb, Please make the following change,

```
resources :jobs do
    post :update_work_flow,  on: :collection
```

In Js, you have specified as 'post' method, while in routes, you have specified a 'get' method. Try changing to post and the code should work.

Comment: thanks for reply, I replaced get with post but still it is not working. if you have another option for this task, please suggest me ..